# show current user location?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know this has been asked by many others. I just wanted to know that by now the simulator is still unable to detect the current location (it always detects it as Cupertino). Is this true? Has apple actually done some update on this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the location in iPhone Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator)

Comment: You say above that it is a duplicate, and here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, and they won't. The simulator is a joke. It should only be used when fiddling around before you get approved for the iOS Dev program. All actual debugging should be done on a device. Period.

Comment: You can now choose locations, which makes simulator useful for testing.

Answer (score -2):

In the simulator you cant see the current location,if u write code for to display current location, in simulator it shows default sanfrancisco location.Run That application in device then it shows curtrent location

Comment: actually, with xcode 4 you can simulate different locations in the debugger bar. why the hell do you answer a year old question, and then with the same answer that was already given ?