# Set current user location in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, mapkit

Is there a way to set the current user location in iPhone simulator on Xcode 4?, I want the simulator to show a different location other than Cupertino.

Comment: "In my delegate callback, I check to see if I'm running in a simulator (#if TARGET_ IPHONE_SIMULATOR) and if so, I supply my own, pre-looked-up, Lat/Long. To my knowledge, there's no other way." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator/214455#214455

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the location in iPhone Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator)

Comment: See nevan king's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541973/simulating-location-changes-for-startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12637537/194544

Answer (score 9):

Yes, from the simulator's menu choose `Debug > Location > Custom Location...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can Simulate Location by selecting 
Product -> Debug -> Simulate Location and select Location option from Xcode tool.

This is shown in following figure:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add GPX file to get the current location on simulator.
[image]