# Testing a location based iOS application using KIF

Tags: ios, testing, geolocation

I want to write tests for an iOS app that are location dependent, like if you are at place `A` (I mean geo-location) this testStep should fail and that one should succeed and in location `B` the situation is the other way around,

Is there a way to simulate being at a location for KIF tests, like defining a stepForBeingAtLocation , for the simulator obviously, and not by manually choosing a gpx file for each test separately,

EDIT: to make it more clear, I want to do it in my tests, so it should be done in my code or with calling an external script or in some automatic way, I want to run tests that should happen in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Simulator is able to simulate different locations.

Select the iOS Simulator app, and from its OS X menu bar, look under Debug -> Location.

Comment: I want to do it in my tests, so it should be done in my code or with calling an external script or in some automatic way, I want to run tests that should happen in different locations.

Comment: I think it's possible to simulate moving locations within a GPX file, does that help? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541973/simulating-location-changes-for-startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges

Comment: nope, you see, I have all these tests, for one I need to be at one place and for the other I need to be at another place, for each test, obviously, the app starts from scratch, and the motion (if I wanted to simulate motion with a gpx file) restarts as well