# I can't get Swift to give me a user's location

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get the user's location in Swift. Using the code below. But when I call

let currentloc = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate , it returns a nil value. The code below is above the let currentloc line in the script.

```
     self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Comment: Is the delegate method called? Because the location is not "immediate". You have to retrieve it through the delegate method.

Comment: I'm not sure. what is the delegate method?

Comment: `self.locationManager.delegate`: Why did you put this line? `
- locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`

Comment: Oh I see, but the problem is that I am returning labels with the distance that each place is from the user, so I dont know how to work it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you:

1. `import Corelocation` + `import MapKit` in your class.
2. conform to the `MKMapViewDelegate` and `CLLocationManagerDelegate`
3. instantiate the locationmanager: `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()` in your class variables
4. in your viewDidLoad try:

   ```
   self.locationManager.delegate = self
   self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
   self.locationManager. requestAlwaysAuthorization()
   self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
   self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
   ```
5. Add the following delegate method to print your location:

   ```
   func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
   print(locations.last!.coordinate)
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you. But I think it is a problem regarding updating user location and how it isnt instant. See, I have a loop that prints labels with their distance from the user, soI am trying to make it instant. it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are you using a simulator or a real device?

Comment: A simulator (iPhone 6)

Comment: Simulators don't work with current locations, you have to set them manually. Read into this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16082525/6414904

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

- Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Options -> Allow Location Simulation must be checked and try providing a default location, don't leave it set to "none"

When you test on simulator, you have to provide a default location, please check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887820/4887400

Comment: Thanks, but does this mean that my code will work on a device when I call 'locationManager.location.coordinates' and have my code using the location straight after it? Or would I have to call the rest of the code in the locationManager delegate??