# iOS: CLLocationManager's didEnterRegion not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have successfully managed to register a region or monitoring, I know this because the `didStartMonitoringForRegion` method was fired.

I have a simple test app with one `MKMapView` where I can see my current location, I also have my region drawn on the map as a red circle so I can actually 'physically' see at what point I am entering or exiting this region. In the `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` methods I have a `UIAlertView` that fires.

A little while ago I decided to leave the office and take a walk with my iPhone 4, to see if this would work. I started in the middle of the region (which is about 200m in radius), my app was in the foreground the whole time. I walked a couple blocks and exited the region, nothing happened.

I read on SO (I think) that sometimes it only works when you exit the region by a certain distance, so I kept on walking.

After another 200m or so I gave up as the `UIAlertView` still wasn't showing, and started to walk back. Obviously, upon re-entering the region, `didEnterRegion` wasn't firing either.

I am not calling `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` anywhere in my code, should I be?? I'm only really creating the region and calling `[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion]`.

The `CLLocationManagerDelegate` is my app delegate, and it seems fine as my `didStartMonitoringForRegion` is firing properly.

Am I missing anything else?

Comment: You don't need to call `startUpdatingLocation`. I don't see a problem from what you tell. Maybe it helps when you post some code.

Comment: Did you verify that inside the region `[monitoredRegion containsCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate]` is true and outside it is false?

Comment: @phix23 Actually I didn't try that, I will now, thanks!

Comment: @PaulG: have u fixed above issue am getting same problem in my application.can you explain me how you have fixed that

Comment: @sabir I never got this to work properly so I ended up doing my own distance calculation in the `didUpdateToLocation` method.

Comment: @PaulG:For me didenter and didExit regions are never been invoked..

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states that region monitoring works independently from the other location services. That means it should be enough to call startMonitoringForRegion.

Make sure:

- [CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable] returns YES
- CLLocationManager.monitoredRegions contains valid regions

**NOTE:**
The doc specifies that events make take between 3-5 minutes to fire.

> In iOS 6, regions with a radius between 1 and 400 meters work better
>   on iPhone 4S or later devices. (In iOS 5, regions with a radius
>   between 1 and 150 meters work better on iPhone 4S and later devices.)
>   On these devices, an app can expect to receive the appropriate region
>   entered or region exited notification within 3 to 5 minutes on
>   average, if not sooner.

And

> Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters
>   or more from its previous notification. It should not expect
>   notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the
>   device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager
>   is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner.

I hope this helps.

Comment: regionMonitoringEnabled is deprecated but I tried it and yes it works. Thanks for the response btw! Hmmm, according to your response I gave up too soon and should have walked further.

Comment: Changed it to regionMonitoringAvailable which is the new call. Btw, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator for an easier way to test this than walking for ages.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note down (If you are simulating the location):

If entering and exiting is never called even though you think you have done everything right in the code make sure to check if you disabled location simulation by:

Going to the Product -> Scheme -> edit scheme -> Options tab -> Disable location simulation.

I was trying to test my region monitoring by physically walking out and in the region while simulating location and it was not working for me precisely because of this reason.