# Location manager giving really bad coordinates

Tags: objective-c, gps, location, core-location

I tried writing a coordinate using Core Location, and it's running nicely, only thing is, it's a vegetable when it comes to coordinates.

This is the code that gets the coordinates.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
if (startingLocation == nil)
    self.startingLocation = newLocation;
NSString *latitudeString  = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
latitudeLabel.text = latitudeString;

NSString *longitudeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
longitudeLabel.text = longitudeString;

NSString *horizontalAccuracyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g",newLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
horizontalAccuraryLabel.text = horizontalAccuracyString;

NSString *altitudeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g",newLocation.altitude];
altitudeLabel.text = altitudeString;

NSString *verticalAccuracyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g",newLocation.verticalAccuracy];
verticalAccuracyLabel.text = verticalAccuracyString;

CLLocationDistance distance = [newLocation getDistanceFrom:startingLocation];
NSString *distanceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g",distance];
distanceTraveledLabel.text = distanceString;
```

}

It's giving me Lat: 37.7858 Long: -122.406 which is somewhere in USA, while I'm running the code from Europe, Romania...

Could it be because it's running from a simulator?

Also I know the locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation is deprecated, but I tried doing it with:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

but I don't know how to access the elements of [location lastObject].

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That lat & long combination is San Francisco, which is the home base for many commuting (via a posh luxury commuter bus) Apple employees.

You can set the location that your simulator is working with pretty easily:

[image: you can set your preferred location in the iPhone simulator]

Latitude & Longitude for Bucharest is "44.4325" & "26.103889", as far as I know.

As for accessing the elements of "`[location lastObject]`", the object(s) in that array will be a [CLLocation object](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocation) which has a "`coordinate`" property. If you get a "`didUpdateLocations:`" delegate method being called, that array will always have at least one location (which is what you access via "`lastObject`").