# Capture debug information in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I have a swift program that perform some task based on core location and etc.
For most part everything works well except when I am at this particular location. 
In my program I have print statements for debugging purpose and I can see what’s going on in xcode when the program running on my phone. So my question is how can I capture the print statement in some kind of log to view while I am not connected to xcode so I can see what is going on when I am at this particular location?

Comment: I think the iOS simulator has a simulate location feature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator not sure if that helps you ?

Comment: Hi, is not the simulator issue. I need to know what my application is capturing while the phone physically is at different locations

Answer (score 0):

There are several logging tools for iOs. I am using [JEToolkit](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/JEToolkit). Best feature is realtime logging in HUD so you can see all necessary information for you.

[image]