# Is it possible to set a location automatically for xcode UI testing?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I am currently writing tests for my app on xcode, and was wondering if there is a line of code I could use that would run my tests using an pre determined location service? I know it is possible to do it manually by clicking on the arrow when the test is running, but i want it automatically? I cant find any documentation or similar questions online.

Anyone know of anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8175468/4475605 & https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/using-xcode-to-test-location-services/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution to this is going on simulator > Debug > Location > Custom Location > Then add the Lat and long in.

[image]