# Location Manager not work in simulator But run in Iphone properly

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, core-location, cllocationmanager

**App runs in iPhone but when i am trying to run in simulator its shows error  as given in image**

please help me & thank you in advanced

// THIS IS MY CODE:

```
    locationManager.delegate = self
    var locManager = CLLocationManager()
    locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()


    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse ||
        CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
    {
        let latitude1 = locManager.location!.coordinate.latitude.description
        latitude = latitude1

        let longitude1 = locManager.location!.coordinate.longitude.description
        longnitude = longitude1
        print(latitude)
        print(longnitude)
    } else {
        latitude = ""
        longnitude = ""

    }
```

[image]

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator this could be your answer

Comment: @Joe i was tried this but not work

Comment: Did you tried any default  Simulate location from Xcode.Explain me what you have tried.so,i can get better understanding and  we find the way to fix your problem.

Comment: I just created a test project.i have no problem running in simulator.Are you using proper delegate....

Comment: can you show us some code...

Comment: wait in add my code in my questions @Joe

Comment: did you import Core Location and explain what o/p you getting from the phone..

Comment: getting latitude & longitude as output in iphone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126218/discussion-between-siddharth-shah-and-joe).

Comment: No worries mate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: Tested in Xcode simulator(Swift 3)

**Update your plist:**

Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description == Some Value

```
 import UIKit
 import MapKit
 import CoreLocation

  class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let location = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    print(location)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
{
    print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
}
```

Output from the code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to import the framework as
`import CoreLocation`