# Does iOS Simulator not have Current Location

Tags: ios, geolocation, ios-simulator, react-native-ios

I'm messing about with React Native, and I came across this other post: [Permission Denied Geolocation React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539652/permission-denied-geolocation-in-react-native). I wanted to append another question onto that post, but I do not have a high enough ranking to make comments.

My question is, does the iOS simulator not have the current location ability automatically? I know that macOS apps in Xcode have full networking and geolocation abilities, thus I don't need to specify a location when using CLLocationManager. I'm trying to understand the reasoning and limitations behind the iOS simulator; specifically as to why it would not simply behave like any other VM and just use the host's wifi for basic network and location settings? Why would I need to specify a location upon simulator startup?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, apple does not support 'real' gps through the iOS simulator, but it does provide you with a variety of other options as you can see on this screenshot I made for you:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6lOm.png)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

To get the current location in simulator you have to add **GPX file** in your project.

Project->New file -> iOS->Resource->select GPX file

**Here is a simple GPX file . You just change the name and lat/long.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<gpx
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
version="1.1" 
creator="gpx-poi.com">

   <wpt lat="lat" lon="long">
      <name>YourLocation</name>
   </wpt>

</gpx>
```