# "Location Permission Denied" on ios simulator even after setting custom location in Features->Location->customlocation

Tags: ios, react-native, permissions, location, google-geolocation

I am new to mobile development. I am trying to access my current location in the ios simulator running IOS 14.4 and I keep getting the "Location Permission denied" error even after setting up the **custom location in the simulator** as suggested by some answers on this platform, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539652/permission-denied-geolocation-in-react-native). The code that I am running is this

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      this.setState({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        coordinates: this.state.coordinates.concat({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude
        })
      });
    },
    error => {
      Alert.alert(error.message.toString());
    },
    {
      showLocationDialog: true,
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 20000,
      maximumAge: 0
    }
  );
```

I have set up these permissions in my info-plist.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Will you allow this app to always know your location?</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Do you allow this app to know your current location?</string>
```

I am not entirely sure what I might be doing wrong here. This is the only code currently that tries to access the location.

***Is there any other reason why this error should persist even after setting the current location as the custom location in Features->Location->customlocation? as suggested by the other answers on this platform.***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the location in iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator)

Comment: No, the issue is that even after setting the custom location as suggested I still get the error.

Comment: @newdevguy check new solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's required to ask location access permission at run-time before you run code that requires location access.

`react-native-permissions` is the standard library for cross-platform permissions

Follow installation instruction here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions

```js
import { request, PERMISSIONS, RESULT } from "react-native-permissions";

function getUserLocation() {
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      this.setState({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        coordinates: this.state.coordinates.concat({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        }),
      });
    },
    (error) => {
      Alert.alert(error.message.toString());
    },
    {
      showLocationDialog: true,
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 20000,
      maximumAge: 0,
    }
  );
}
request(PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_ALWAYS).then((result) => {
  switch (result) {
    case RESULTS.UNAVAILABLE:
      console.log(
        "This feature is not available (on this device / in this context)"
      );
      break;
    case RESULTS.DENIED:
      console.log(
        "The permission has not been requested / is denied but requestable"
      );
      break;
    case RESULTS.LIMITED:
      console.log("The permission is limited: some actions are possible");
      break;
    case RESULTS.GRANTED:
      console.log("The permission is granted");
      // Permission has been granted - app can request location coordinates
      getUserLocation();
      break;
    case RESULTS.BLOCKED:
      console.log("The permission is denied and not requestable anymore");
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you approve answer for future developer reference

Comment: @newsdevguy was this solution even working or you have just approved it?