# I'm trying to find present location, But i'm not getting present location

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to find present location coordinates,but my program not calling `didUpdateLocations` method. And Also i add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in `info.plist`. Any help please (i'm using Version 7.2 (7C68)). I'm Testing simulator only.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var location: CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let location = CLLocationManager()
    location.delegate = self
    location.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    location.startUpdatingLocation()
    location.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()



    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let cord = locations[0] as CLLocation
   let lati =  cord.coordinate.latitude
    let long = cord.coordinate.longitude
    print(lati,"",long)

}


}
```

Comment: you are testing in real device or simulator?

Comment: I'm testing simulator only.

Comment: You need to set location in simulator

Comment: Then simulate your position to one predefined GPX provided by xCode, and  check if you start to receive the locations update

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175468/2963352 check this link

Comment: I set the location using Debug-Location-Custom.But it also not worked.

Comment: Yes i got solution i'm called startUpdatingLocation method before setting permission.