# How to test map heading function in mobile emulator?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mapbox, heading

I have just developed map application with Mapbox in React Native.
And I would like to check heading function in IOS emulator.
What is the solution? Only can I check this on Real Device?
Cheers!

Comment: As in the accepted answer, you can simulate a user location, but heading (the direction the user is pointed) cannot be simulated — you must test this on device.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

open IOS Simulator. Go to menu then Debug > Location > Custom Location. You can set Latitude and Longitude there and can test on your application.
this might be helpful  [issue#214416](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator)